# HTTP apache server Error 503 service unavailable

Tags: apache

I have this problem message.

```
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance 
in localhost apache downtime or capacity problems. 

Please try again later.
```

yesterday i opened the localhost and it was fine
but today i have this error every time i'm using fedora
what is the problem please? and how can i solve it?
thank you

Comment: Check the Apache logs, and those of whatever app or framework you are using. Try seeing whether a static file can be downloaded. I'm afraid you supplied insufficient data for a meaningful answer.

Comment: To make good question, you have to supply enough data as possible. Like Iserni said, you have to check the Apache log then show the parts that you think it useful for your case to allow someone answer your question. Good luck.