# Apache Atlas: HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-atlas

I have also seen the following two similar links, but they were different from mine that I will describe it in this post:

- [Apache Atlas: Http 503 Service Unavailable Error when connecting from Java Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610612/apache-atlas-http-503-service-unavailable-error-when-connecting-from-java-clien)
- [HTTP apache server Error 503 service unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020479/http-apache-server-error-503-service-unavailable)

I'm trying to run Apache Atlas on my local computer. So I have cloned it from the official repository.

From the *README.md* file of the repository I have entered the following two commands and it runs successfully:

1. `mvn clean install -DskipTests -X`
2. `mvn clean -DskipTests package -Pdist,embedded-hbase-solr`

[image]

These are the commands and changes I tried:

1. `tar xzvf apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-server.tar.gz`
2. `cd apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/`
3. `python2.7 atlas_start.py`

After running the python script, I got this log:

```
configured for local hbase.
hbase started.
configured for local solr.
solr.xml doesn't exist in /bigdata/atlas/distro/target/apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/data/solr, copying from /bigdata/atlas/distro/target/apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/solr/server/solr/solr.xml
solr started.
setting up solr collections...
starting atlas on host localhost
starting atlas on port 21000

Apache Atlas Server started!!!
```

It seems that it doesn't have any problem, but whenever I want to test it with *curl*, something bad has happened?

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs/head
```

Error:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs/head</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>503</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Service Unavailable</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>-</td></tr>
</table>
<hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.31.v20200723</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the **application.log** file:

```
2021-03-13 17:05:37,484 INFO  - [main:] ~ Loading atlas-application.properties from file:/bigdata/atlas/distro/target/apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/atlas-application.properties (ApplicationProperties:137)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,503 INFO  - [main:] ~ Using graphdb backend 'janus' (ApplicationProperties:317)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,503 INFO  - [main:] ~ Using storage backend 'hbase2' (ApplicationProperties:328)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,503 INFO  - [main:] ~ Using index backend 'solr' (ApplicationProperties:339)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,515 INFO  - [main:] ~ Atlas is running in MODE: PROD. (ApplicationProperties:343)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,516 INFO  - [main:] ~ Setting solr-wait-searcher property 'true' (ApplicationProperties:349)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,516 INFO  - [main:] ~ Setting index.search.map-name property 'false' (ApplicationProperties:353)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,516 INFO  - [main:] ~ Setting atlas.graph.index.search.max-result-set-size = 150 (ApplicationProperties:363)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,517 INFO  - [main:] ~ Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.db-cache = true (ApplicationProperties:375)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,517 INFO  - [main:] ~ Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20 (ApplicationProperties:375)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,517 INFO  - [main:] ~ Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.db-cache-size = 0.5 (ApplicationProperties:375)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,517 INFO  - [main:] ~ Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.tx-cache-size = 15000 (ApplicationProperties:375)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,518 INFO  - [main:] ~ Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.tx-dirty-size = 120 (ApplicationProperties:375)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,535 INFO  - [main:] ~ 
########################################################################################
                               Atlas Server (STARTUP)

    project.name:   apache-atlas
    project.description:    Metadata Management and Data Governance Platform over Hadoop
    build.user: root
    build.epoch:    1615641603895
    project.version:    3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    build.version:  3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    vc.revision:    7eab2cb8d53ca4c86366e896119a1d7906ccb5b3
    vc.source.url:  scm:git:git://git.apache.org/atlas.git/atlas-webapp
######################################################################################## (Atlas:215)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,535 INFO  - [main:] ~ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> (Atlas:216)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,535 INFO  - [main:] ~ Server starting with TLS ? false on port 21000 (Atlas:217)
2021-03-13 17:05:37,538 INFO  - [main:] ~ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< (Atlas:218)
2021-03-13 17:05:39,801 INFO  - [main:] ~ No authentication method configured.  Defaulting to simple authentication (LoginProcessor:102)
2021-03-13 17:05:40,136 WARN  - [main:] ~ Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable (NativeCodeLoader:60)
2021-03-13 17:05:40,351 INFO  - [main:] ~ Logged in user root (auth:SIMPLE) (LoginProcessor:77)
2021-03-13 17:05:41,716 INFO  - [main:] ~ Not running setup per configuration atlas.server.run.setup.on.start. (SetupSteps$SetupRequired:189)
2021-03-13 17:05:43,892 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 1 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:44,989 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 2 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:46,092 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 3 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:47,194 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 4 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:48,295 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 5 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:49,397 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 6 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:50,499 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 7 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:51,601 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 8 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:52,703 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 9 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:53,805 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 10 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:54,907 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 11 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:56,009 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 12 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:57,110 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 13 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:58,212 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 14 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:05:59,313 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 15 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:00,414 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 16 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:01,517 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 17 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:02,618 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 18 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:03,720 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 19 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:04,822 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 20 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:16,941 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 30, give up (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:196)
2021-03-13 17:06:16,958 WARN  - [main:] ~ Retrieve cluster id failed (ConnectionImplementation:576)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionImplementation.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionImplementation.java:307)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.lambda$createConnection$0(ConnectionFactory.java:230)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.runAs(User.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:128)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase2.HBaseCompat2_0.createConnection(HBaseCompat2_0.java:46)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase2.HBaseStoreManager.<init>(HBaseStoreManager.java:314)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:440)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:411)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.builder.GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.build(GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.java:50)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:161)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:132)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:112)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.initJanusGraph(AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.java:182)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.getGraphInstance(AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.java:169)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.getGraph(AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.java:278)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider.getGraphInstance(AtlasGraphProvider.java:52)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider.get(AtlasGraphProvider.java:98)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55698c0f.CGLIB$get$0(<generated>)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55698c0f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ec479fde.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55698c0f.get(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.atlas.web.setup.KerberosAwareListener.contextInitialized(KerberosAwareListener.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.apache.atlas.web.service.EmbeddedServer.start(EmbeddedServer.java:113)
    at org.apache.atlas.Atlas.main(Atlas.java:133)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1.exec(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient.run(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-03-13 17:06:18,044 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for list of /hbase, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 1 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:19,144 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for list of /hbase, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 2 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:20,246 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for list of /hbase, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 3 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:21,348 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for list of /hbase, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 4 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
2021-03-13 17:06:22,449 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for list of /hbase, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 5 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
.
.
.
2021-03-13T13:58:36.264Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1615643246874, pause=100, maxAttempts=16}, java.io.IOException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.getTableState(MetaTableAccessor.java:1164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin$6.rpcCall(HBaseAdmin.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin$6.rpcCall(HBaseAdmin.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallable.call(RpcRetryingCallable.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:107)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.get(ConnectionImplementation.java:2117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionImplementation.java:814)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionImplementation.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HRegionLocator.getRegionLocation(HRegionLocator.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionLocator.getRegionLocation(RegionLocator.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionLocator.getRegionLocation(RegionLocator.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.prepare(RegionServerCallable.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:105)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1.exec(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient.run(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-03-13 17:28:37,365 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for list of /hbase, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 1 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)
```

Would someone help me how to install apache atlas properly?

**PS** I have also tried `2.1.0` version. Whenever I want to run it through `atlas_start.py` script, error has been occured.

```
Exception: [Errno 13] Permission denied 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "atlas_start.py", line 163, in <module>
    returncode = main()
  File "atlas_start.py", line 73, in main
    mc.expandWebApp(atlas_home)
  File "./distro/target/apache-atlas-2.1.0-bin/apache-atlas-2.1.0/bin/atlas_config.py", line 162, in expandWebApp
    jar(atlasWarPath)
  File "./distro/target/apache-atlas-2.1.0-bin/apache-atlas-2.1.0/bin/atlas_config.py", line 215, in jar
    process = runProcess(commandline)
  File "./distro/target/apache-atlas-2.1.0-bin/apache-atlas-2.1.0/bin/atlas_config.py", line 251, in runProcess
    p = subprocess.Popen(commandline, stdout=stdoutFile, stderr=stderrFile, shell=shell)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2021-03-13 17:06:18,044 WARN  - [ReadOnlyZKClient-localhost:2181@0x39acd1f1:] ~ 0x39acd1f1 to localhost:2181 failed for list of /hbase, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 1 (ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1:192)

The error is about failing to get /hbase zknode in zookeeper. Can you verify that HBase is up and running? HBase logs would be in apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/hbase/logs directory.

BTW, I built the same profile, embedded-hbase-solr, from latest master few minutes back and was able to start successfully.

Comment: Thank for your comment. Would you please provide the complete story about how you try to run it? The documentation is not that complete.

Comment: I followed the instructions in http://atlas.apache.org/#/BuildInstallation and http://atlas.apache.org/#/Installation:  
- Build Atlas with command:  
```
mvn clean -DskipTests package -Pdist,embedded-hbase-solr
```  
- Install and run with following commands:  
```
tar -xzvf apache-atlas-{project.version}-server.tar.gz
cd apache-atlas-{project.version}
export MANAGE_LOCAL_HBASE=true
export MANAGE_LOCAL_SOLR=true
bin/atlas_start.py
```

Comment: I have tried the same commands (but I try `python2.7 atlas_start.py` for the last one), but I get the error which I have written in the **P.S** part of the post.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me

```sh
# Tell HBase whether it should manage it's own instance of Zookeeper or not.
# export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

in this file: {atlas}/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh

https://serverfault.com/questions/599661/could-not-start-zk-at-requested-port-of-2181-while-export-hbase-manages-zk-fals